# How to replace first column in text file?

Tags: python

I have file like this

```
6     5     1         2.364       0.022
6     5     2        30.364       2.866
6     5     5         2.351       0.022
6     5     6        44.606       2.866
6     6     1         2.372       0.022
6     6     2        33.290       2.866
6     6     5         2.290       0.022
6     6     6        43.799       2.866
6     7     1         2.414       0.022
6     7     2        37.071       2.866
6     7     5         2.281       0.022
```

I want to change 6 to 1.I have thought of

```
line.contains
```

but 6 also appears in other columns.

Comment: Your question does not seem to contain any code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import re
with open(...) as f:
    print re.sub('^6', '1', f.read(), flags=re.MULTILINE)
```

---

```
s = '''6     5     1         2.364       0.022
6     5     2        30.364       2.866
6     5     5         2.351       0.022
6     5     6        44.606       2.866
6     6     1         2.372       0.022
6     6     2        33.290       2.866
6     6     5         2.290       0.022
6     6     6        43.799       2.866
6     7     1         2.414       0.022
6     7     2        37.071       2.866
6     7     5         2.281       0.022'''

import re
print re.sub('^6', '1', s, flags=re.MULTILINE)
```

---

And if you don't want to use `re`, you could try (although I would recommend to use `re`) :

```
lines = []
for line in open(...):
    parts = line.split()
    parts[0] = '1'
    lines.append('\t'.join(parts))
 print '\n'.join(lines)
```

or:

```
lines = []
for line in open(...):
    lines.append(line.replace('6', '1', 1))
 print '\n'.join(lines)
```

Comment: You could write that a lot more simply as `with open(...) as f: lines = ['1' + x[1:] for x in f]`

Comment: @KurtStutsman even better would be to use str.replace('6', '1', 1) for each line but I wanted to be as readable as possible...

Comment: @EcirHana you got your arguments reversed there but you're right.

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest using `sed` instead of Python.

```
sed -e 's/^6/1/' input.txt > output.txt
```

Comment: @RichardRublev it writes a new file output.txt in my example. You can use the `-i` option if you want to modify the input file.